# mongodb queries in Java

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am new to mongodb, I have a JSON like this:

```
{
    "first_name" : "John",
    "last_name"  : "Smith",
    "address" : {
        "street" : "123 Main Street",
        "city"   : "Anytown",
        "state"  : "NY"
   }
}
```

Now I want to find all documents where "street" = "123" (say). In mongo shell, I do it as follows:

```
db.collection_name.find(
  {
    'address.street' : '123'
  }
)
```

In Java if I want to find documents where "firstname" = "John", I do it as:

```
BasicDBObject nameQuery = new BasicDBObject();
nameQuery.put("firstname", "John");
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(nameQuery);
```

I cannot figure out for adress.street, I have tried something but it didn't work.

I tried this:

```
addressQuery.put("address.street", "123");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you suggest should work. This works for me:

```
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection(...);
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(new BasicDBObject("address.street", "123 Main Street"));
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(cursor.next()); //prints the object
}
```

Comment: I have tried it. But it does not work for me! Have you tried it? Did you got the result?

Comment: @stalin Are you sure there is no typo in `address.street` and in `123 Main Street` when you create the DBObject? Yes I just tried it with you data and it worked.

Comment: @stalin Just to be sure, could it be that you are trying with `new BasicDBObject("address.street", "123")` instead of `new BasicDBObject("address.street", "123 Main Street")`?

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I was making some mistake. "address.street" is correct.